# Trimming inconsistent values in a column

Tags: sql, ssms

I have such an issue.

On column namely t.DC has sometimes other values after the number for example

```
01 ROYAL

40 ABC
```

Trying to see if there is anything that can erase those names after digits leaving just the numbers there.

```
select t.Chain, t.DC, t.Item#

FROM t
```

When I try to write like this "

```
 CASE WHEN t.DC IN (01, 02, 08, 21, 22, 30, 32, 40, 55, 62) THEN t.DC ELSE '01' END AS DC"
```

I am getting an error " Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '21 CE' to data type int."

Answer (score 0):

Well you could try something like this:

```
SELECT t.Chain,
       CASE WHEN t.DC LIKE "DC%" THEN SUBSTRING(t.DC, 3, 2)
            WHEN t.DC LIKE "[0-9][0-9]%" THEN LEFT(t.DC, 2)
       END AS DC,
       t.Item
FROM t
```

Comment: what about trimming everything after first 2 numbers?

Comment: When I try to write like this " CASE WHEN t.DC IN (01, 02, 08, 21, 22, 30, 32, 40, 55, 62) THEN t.DC
            ELSE '01' 
   
       END AS DC," I am getting an error " Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '21 CE' to data type int."

Comment: In order for that to work you would need to wrap each value in quotes like "01", "02", etc. But doing a simple regular expression test as I laid out captures every possible case, and the `LEFT(t.DC, 2)` part picks just the numbers whether there's trailing data or not.